# Network request in each item contained in a List not displaying data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am fetching data within a `MovieItem` component. When I just display one `MovieItem` this works correctly. However when I move this card into a `List` the data isn't fetched correctly and nothing is displayed.

My code looks something like this

MovieModel

```
class MovieModel: ObservableObject {
   var movie: Movie

   fetchMovie(movieId) {
     ...request stuff from core data...
     self.movie = movie
   }
}
```

ListView

```
struct ListView: View {
   @ObservedObject var movies: [Movie(name: "Titanic", id: 1)]

   var body: some View {

      List {
         ForEach(movies) { movie in
            MovieItem(movie: movie)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

MovieItem

```
struct MovieItem: View {
    @ObservedObject var movieModel: MovieModel
    var movie: Movie

    var body: some View {
      Text(movie.name)
    }
    .onAppear {
       movieModel.fetchMovie(movie)
    }
}
```

Is it obvious to anyone what's wrong and the approach to take to get this to work?

Comment: what's `OtherModel`? is it an array of your `MovieModel`, or something else? Show a minimum reproducible code, so we can run it and try to "fix" it.

Comment: Peter I think you need to lazy load the list as you are doing api calling when list visible so you need to do the api calling with lazy load.

Comment: @ChiragShah do you mean use `LazyVStack` - I tried this to begin with but also didnt work. Maybe `Combine` needs to be used? Not 100% sure what the correct approach is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this structure, using **one** `class MovieModel: ObservableObject` and
passing this model to other views using `.environmentObject(movieModel)`.

See this link [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app), it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}

class MovieModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var movies: [Movie] = [Movie(id: 1, name: "Titanic")]
    
    func fetchMovie(id: Int) {
        //...request
        // for testing
        if let index = movies.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id}) {
            movies[index].name = movies[index].name + " II"
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllMovies() {
        // for testing
        movies = [Movie(id: 1, name: "Titanic"), Movie(id: 2, name: "Mickey Mouse")]
    }
}

struct Movie: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
    //....
}

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var movieModel = MovieModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(movieModel.movies) { movie in
                MovieItem(movie: movie)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            movieModel.fetchAllMovies()
        }
        .environmentObject(movieModel)
    }
}

struct MovieItem: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var movieModel: MovieModel
    var movie: Movie
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(movie.name)
            .onAppear {
                movieModel.fetchMovie(id: movie.id)
            }
    }
}
```

If you plan to use ios17, then have a look at this link [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) for how to manage data in your app.